# How to mark wordpress posts as read?

Tags: wordpress

I want to make something similar to what Techcrunch have on their site. For now I use wordpress plugin that mark posts as new and think to modified it to achieve similar functionality but the plugin won't work for ajax loading.
What I want to make is when user open new post, automatically after he returns to the front page, title and excerpt of the post to be color faded. How to make this with setting cookie and make it to work for title and excerpt on any page (for post list, grids etc.), instead of single post page. And also I need this to work when new posts are loaded with ajax.

**I tried this function and It's work ok, but now I need text label to change to Old after user open the post, and then to inject some css to the title. Also, this is not perfect, because I want all posts to be New on first visit, an then to change to Old after user open them.**

```
function wpb_lastvisit_set_cookie() {
    if ( ! is_admin() && ! isset( $_COOKIE['lastvisit'] ) ) {
        setcookie( 'lastvisit', $current, time() + 3600 * 24 * 100, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_lastvisit_set_cookie');


function wpb_lastvisit_the_title ( $title, $id ) {

if ( !in_the_loop() || is_singular() || get_post_type( $id ) == 'page' ) return $title;

// if no cookie then just return the title 

if ( !isset($_COOKIE['lastvisit']) ||  $_COOKIE['lastvisit'] == '' ) return $title;
$lastvisit = $_COOKIE['lastvisit'];
$publish_date = get_post_time( 'U', true, $id );
if ($publish_date > $lastvisit) $title .= ' New';
if ($publish_date < $lastvisit) $title .= ' Old';
return $title;

}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpb_lastvisit_the_title', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Georgi, Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service. We expect you to do an honest attempt at solving the issue yourself first and ask questions here if you get stuck with your code at some point. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Please don't post your code in comments as it's hard to read that way. Edit your question and include it there.

Comment: I edit the post.

Comment: From your code, you're setting one cookie (`lastvisit`) for all posts. That won't work if your plan is to mark each post as read individually. You'll need to either create a cookie per each read post (eg. `lastvisit-POST-ID-HERE`), or create a single cookie that stores the ID of all of the posts the user has read so far.

Comment: That's what I want to do, but I'm not sure how to set cookie to store the ID of every read post, can you show me some example, please! And also how to change the style of the title based on this cookie?